# How to remove extraneous spaces from Python array?

Tags: python, arrays

I have a python array containing a mixed set of values that looks somewhat like the example below:

```
['0012 ', ' 318422 ', ' www.example.com']
```

My question is, how can I easily remove leading and trailing spaces from values in the array, such that it looks like this:

```
['0012', '318422', 'www.example.com']
```

Answer (score 6):

Like so

```
[x.strip() for x in mylist]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map` and `strip`:

```
a = ['0012 ', ' 318422 ', ' www.example.com']
clean_a = map(lambda x: x.strip(), a)
```